# EthernetPacket.source() CAPL function interpretation in Vector CANoe

Tags: capl, canoe, automotive

I am new to Vector CANoe, I am trying to find the MAC address of the Ethernet packet being received from real ECU node and sent to another real Node. The two nodes are connected on two ports of the VN5620 device. I was trying to print the MAC address contained in each Etehrnet Frame. But I cannot interpret the way the write window prints the MAC addresses in Vector CANoe tool.

**CAPl Code**

```
`on ethernetPacket ethernetPort::HCP1_eth::Proxy_Gateway.*
{
forwardEthFrames (this);
}
void forwardEthFrames(ethernetPacket * ethPacket)
{
write("MACSource: %x, MACdest: %x",ethPacket.source,ethPacket.destination);
}`
```

**OBTAINED OUTPUT:** MACSource: bdf0ea02, MACdest: 4b37
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Aoz.png)

**Actual MAC Addresses**
Source: 02:ea:f0:bd:37:4b; Destination: 33:33:00:00:00:63

I dont understand why write window prints the MAC address in such a way, if I interpret this correctly the first 4 bytes of Source MAC address is printed as source and the last two bytes are printed as destination. The destination MAC address which should be printed is not printed at all. I do understand that the .source or .destination selectors of ethernetPacket function do follow the network byte order, but what I dont get is why the destinationo is missing?

Any kind of help in this regard would be appreciated.

FYI: The Ethernet Packet follows IPv6 and UDP Multicast